# CloudConvert SWF to MP3 cuts off last part of audio

Tags: mp3

I have been using CloudConvert to convert .swf files to .mp3 .  It works great except all of my files seem to cut off the last few milliseconds of the original audio. Usually it cuts off half of a word or so.

Is there any way to correct this?

I have tried a few different settings, but haven't had any luck.

Comment: This question is off topic as it is about a website. Here, we only deal with software running on a computer – but have you tried using any PC/Mac/Linux software that does this?

Comment: No, I have not. I have restrictions on what I can download, etc.